# Applying a timeout to UDP call receive_from in ASIO

Tags: c++, c++11, networking, asio

I have the following bit of ASIO code, that synchronously reads UDP packets. The problem is if no data packets of the given size have arrived in a given time frame  (30 seconds) I'd like the recieve_from function to return with some kind of error to specif icy timeout.

```
for (;;)
{
  boost::array<char, 1000> recv_buf;
  udp::endpoint remote_endpoint;
  asio::error_code error;

  socket.receive_from(asio::buffer(recv_buf),   // <-- require timeout
      remote_endpoint, 0, error);

  if (error && error != asio::error::message_size)
    throw asio::system_error(error);

  std::string message = make_daytime_string();

  asio::error_code ignored_error;
  socket.send_to(asio::buffer(message),
      remote_endpoint, 0, ignored_error);
}
```

Looking at the documentation non of the UDP oriented calls support a time-out mechanism.

What is the correct way (also portable if possible) for having a time-out with syncronous UDP calls in ASIO?

Comment: Surely there is something equivalent to SO_RCVTIMEO?

Comment: @EJP  I was hoping there'd be, but nothing is mentioned in the docs

Comment: Amazing. You can synthesize it with `select()`, however you do that in asio.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible. By running a synchronous `receive_from` you've blocked code execution by a syscall `recvmsg` from `#include <sys/socket.h>`.

As portability goes, I cannot speak for Windows but a linux/bsd C-flavoured solution would look like this:

```
void SignalHandler(int signal) {
  // do what you need to do, possibly informing about timeout and calling exit()
}

...
struct sigaction signal_action;
signal_action.sa_flags = 0;
sigemptyset(&signal_action.sa_mask);
signal_action.sa_handler = SignalHandler;
if (sigaction(SIGALRM, &signal_action, NULL) == -1) {
  // handle error
}
...
int timeout_in_seconds = 5;
alarm(timeout_in_seconds);
...
socket.receive_from(asio::buffer(recv_buf), remote_endpoint, 0, error);
...
alarm(0);
```

If this is not at all feasible, I would recommend going full async and run it in a `boost::asio::io_service`.